Anaconda Navigator cannot be updated online, nor can packages be updated
Comprehensive Issue Description:
I am facing several issues and would appreciate some help:

UI Update Issue:

I've tried updating the UI multiple times, but I haven't seen any changes no matter how long I wait. I'm seeking a resolution to this problem.


Command Line Update Failure:

When I attempt to run the conda update -n base -c defaults conda command, I receive the following message:
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done

Solving environment: done

==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==

  current version: 4.12.0

  latest version: 24.5.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

# All requested packages already installed.



Software Package Update Issue:

I need to update some software packages, but attempts via both the UI and command line have been unsuccessful. Are there specific differences in the steps required for UI versus command line updates?

What I've Tried:
I've attempted multiple executions of conda update -n base -c defaults conda, but the update still fails.
I've waited for the UI update without observing any changes.
I've tried updating software packages through the UI, which also didn't succeed.
Expected Results:
I expect the UI update to be successful, reflecting the changes.
I hope to update conda correctly to the latest version and successfully update the required software packages.
Additional Information:
Operating System: ( Windows server 2022)
Conda Version in Use: 4.12.0
Python Version in Use: (3.8.8)
Names and versions of relevant software packages: (all and python 3.8.8)
Please assist in resolving these issues. Thank you!
I've attempted multiple executions of conda update -n base -c defaults conda, but the update still fails.
I've waited for the UI update without observing any changes.
I've tried updating software packages through the UI, which also didn't succeed.
